# How to Find a Specific Keyword from the beginning of the Word Document in VBA?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, find, document

I am using Word VBA. I want to find a specific keyword "MyTest" from the beginning of the document, and then repeat until all of occurrences are found. How to do so?

I use macro record, and get the following codes:

```
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "MyTest"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
```

This seems only start the find from the current position and will return one instance of the keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro recorder will not give you the best code as it can only record what you do on screen. This means that it always works with the `Selection` object, i.e. whatever you have selected on screen.

Instead you should use a `Range` object set to the the part of the document you want to work with. Unless you are using `ReplaceAll` you also need to repeatedly execute the `Find` until you have found all the matches.

Below is a generic routine that you can modify.

```
Sub FindSomeTextAndDoSomething(textToFind As String)
  Dim findRange As Range
    
  Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    
  With findRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = textToFind
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    Do While .Execute = True
      'add code here to do something with the found text
      'collapse range to continue
      findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. The only problem is that it seems that you do not bring the current position to the beginning of the range. Or it starts from the beginning by default and you do not need to set it?

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Content` starts from the beginning of the document.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another issue is that I think the found keyword will be selected automatically, so I try to use Select.Range to get the range of the found keyword, but get the wrong result. So, how to get the range of the found keyword properly?

Comment: When you are use a Range object nothing gets selected. Instead the range is redefined to the range of the match. The code you add to the routine needs to work with 'findRange'